# ubuntu 16.04 trying to open port 8443 not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, tcp, netstat, ufw

i need to open port 8443  in OS ubuntu 16.04  but nothing is working first i tried to do a scan port using Nmap:

RESULT :

```
Discovered open port 139/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 445/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 3306/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 902/tcp on 127.0.0.1
```

Then i open the port using ufw  and a get the result :

```
8443/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere   
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

then i tried to display the open tcp port using :

```
netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

the result :
not showing the port 8443

i will appreciate any help

Comment: Which daemon should be listening on port 8443?

Comment: i need it to be able to open a specific application

Comment: And what's the problem with that?

Comment: my question based on what i displayed  is the port 8443 open or closed because i am confused between the result of Nmap and ufw

Comment: What do you confuse about? `ufw` said it is **allowed**, and `nmap` said it is **closed**.

Comment: that what is confusing me how to make nmap display as open port

Comment: open it with your "specific application"

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [CentOS – where are my ports?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/326929/23408) (cross-site duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that have to open the port is the application.

When you issue a `netstat -ntlp` you get something like this:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2955/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1515/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1684/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4445                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2882/fop2_server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6050                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1763/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2763/mysqld
```

The last column (**PID/Program name**) shows the application that opened the port.

Assuming a port like a door to your system, then the thing that you did in *ufw* was like removing a lock in a door, so your application can easily open the door when it starts.

Comment: nop this command display the same result as **netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN**

Comment: Yes. Your **application** must open the port. It's the application the one to blame for not opening the port.